# How to setup Dynamic DNS for small fleet of EC2 instances?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, bind

I've been setting up Amazon EC2 instances for an upcoming project which will involve hosting multiple websites on multiple web servers. They are all micro instances, running Ubuntu Server 64bit.

Here's what I have so far:

- **Web Server** -- Apache
- **Database Server** -- MySQL
- **Development Server** -- Apache & MySQL
- **File Server** -- SVN & Bacula (backups are done to S3 buckets)

Currently there's only one Web server, but I've made an image of it, so once the project starts I can launch as many instances as I need and configure them individually.

Everything has been going smoothly, but I've hit some snags.

My first problem is that many of the instances will need to communicate with each other and I would prefer to use their Private IP to reduce costs and increase performance.  However, should an instance be stopped and restarted, its Private IP changes.  I posted a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/227682/whats-best-practice-for-communication-between-amazon-ec2-instances) yesterday regarding this and its looking like the best solution is to use Dynamic DNS. 
Unfortunately, I've never setup a DNS server before.

> Does anyone know of any detailed
>   walkthroughs on how to do setup a DNS server for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally, decided it was simpler to use Amazon's Route53 service than setup my own DNS Server.

For more information how how I did this, look at my other StackOverflow [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/235756/what-is-preventing-amazons-route-53-from-picking-up-my-ec2-instance-tags).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at power DNS, i think that would work, write your self a script that checks the internal IP and pulls from P DNS and if there different connect to MYSQL table and change it. thats how I do it